# Handling Spring Security Oauth2 on a multiple services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an auth service that uses oauth2 along with keycloak. Then i have 2 different services that both need to know which user is accessing them (directly). Right now i have these options:

1. Auth service sets a jsession cookie by default. So it is stateful. I haven't found a way to make it fully stateless as it needs to save the code from oauth2. I will extract jwt token from it and set it as another cookie. Then i will set my other 2 services as stateless and call them using Bearer token. That works. I found this to be slower, as on every call my services will verify the token with keycloak. I also won't be able to make calls to auth service using Bearer token as it expects cookie-based session.
2. I share my session via redis for every service that i need to. That way i can access all of my services (on same domain) without any need for setting my headers. I can also make internal calls to other services using that same cookie sent from client. And i found it to be much faster. However im not aware of consequences that may lead to.
3. Make other services stateless, dont use security in them, route all my requests through gateway, gateway will convert my session cookie into jwt internally, services will simply decode jwt's as they are always signed by keycloak already since its routed through gateway.

I was wondering what is a common scenario for you guys? Is it a common practice to share sessions? And what scenario is preferable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 is almost the way I'd go: you should keep resources access control on the resources servers which is responsible for keeping it. This resource servers know about the resource internal and business rules. Also, it's pretty easy to [test access control rules](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#unit-tests) on resource servers.

As you pointed out in your edit, if access tokens are JWTs, then resource servers do not need a round trip to the authorization server for each request. A request from resource server to authorization server is required only to fetch tokens public signing key (at startup and each time it is rotated). Tokens are then validated locally by the resource server, with this key.

OAuth2 is thought to work as follow:

- OAuth2 authorisation server have state (user authentication status)
- OAuth2 clients have state (store tokens)
- OAuth2 resource server can (should?) be stateless (receive token with each request)

The sessions on authorization server and client(s) are different things and the authorization server should not share its sessions with other actors (but you could use spring-session to share session between clients).

[Latest recommendations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/297#issue-896744390) are to use only "private" OAuth2 clients, which means **clients running on server you trust** (no, the OAuth2 client should not be a single page or mobile application).

For single page (Angular, React, Vue, ...) and mobile applications, Spring Security team encourages the use of the BFF pattern. I wrote a [tutorial for that](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) using `spring-cloud-gateway` with the `TokenRelay=` filter.

If you are using a server-side rendering engine (Thymeleaf, JSF, ...), then the MVC application can be configured as confidential client and directly send requests (authorized with access tokens) to resource servers. I wrote [another tutorial for that](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_ui). In this tutorial, the resource server and client are merged in a single application but, as the [security requirements are very different](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials), each has its own `SecurityFilterChain` bean.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer! I forgot to mention that i don't have a role role model at all, i only need to be able to know current user id in those services.
My auth service is connected directly to keycloak, it is stateful and sets an jsession cookie at the code evaluation endpoint (default behavior?). Then i wanted to use that same cookie to access all my other services. My "gateway" is currently an nginx proxy. But i don't quite understand why my other services supposed to be stateless? Does it have some security implications and i should not share sessions to other services?

Comment: Spring oauth2 security's default session seems to store jwt token, i can definitely switch my nginx instance to a spring gateway, share session to it from an auth service and then swap cookie to a jwt token during routing, however to me it seems like an additional overhead in something that supposed to just wire my apps together? I don't store any sensitive data inside my session nor cookie, to me it seems secure enough? My frontend app is not decided yet, but it's probably gonna be React, and i would much prefer to send cookie rather than store jwt token on client

Comment: Also the terms are a bit confusing (for me), my auth service is an spring security app, not a keycloak. I think you call it a resource server. But i don't quite get why resource server should be stateless, because every call to it would require it to go to keycloak. And in that case at least for me sharing sessions from that resource server to other clients (microservices) seems like a decent decision perfomance and security wise. If my clients would cache these tokens anyway (to not take these laps everytime) it sounds like a waste since they would duplicate that data anyway

Comment: Read the [OAuth2 essentials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#oauth_essentials) intro to my tutorials for the wording (already linked in the answer). A resource server is an application which expect a `Bearer` access-token in `Authorization` header (most frequently a JWT, which saves the call to the authorization server). Resource servers are generally stateless because it make it 1st class citizen in a world where fault tolerance and upscaling matters (you don't care to which instance a request is routed).

Comment: Because of the token it expect in the request, resource servers are queried by OAuth2 clients. React apps are unsafe OAuth2 clients ("public"). You are right to intend authorizing the requests from react with sessions. See the BFF tutorial I linked to use spring-cloud-gateway instead of your NGINX gateway.

Comment: Last, your access control rules being role based or not doesn't change a thing: this rules should be tested and it should be implemented with the rest of the business rules (in resource servers, a.k.a. REST API micro-services).

Comment: Thanks again, i replicated that bff example and it seems to suit my case. One thing that boggles my mind is that every service that needs current user information needs to be oauth resource service, and my "auth" service that i used before (oauth2Login and sets cookies) is now merged in my gateway app, is that a common thing? Seems like too much responsibility for something that just proxies my routes

Comment: In addition to routing requests, the BFF stores tokens in users sessions and replaces session cookies with a token in authorization header. Handling some headers is a very common task for a gateway and isn't "too much". There is no need for resource servers to call  the BFF to get user data: it is carried by JWTs already.